# Reducing the number of tables used - mySQL

Tags: database-design, architecture

I have a table for tax implementation in my application, but I am not sure the design I have done for the table. Can someone review it?

`val_taxes` is the table which has all types of tax listed in the table

```
CREATE TABLE `val_taxes` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `tax_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tax_value` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `val_taxes` (`id`, `tax_name`, `tax_value`) VALUES
(1, 'SGST', '9.00'),
(2, 'CGST', '9.00'),
(3, 'Service', '1.00'),
(4, 'State', '0.25');
```

`val_tax_group` is the table where multiple tax can be grouped

```
CREATE TABLE `val_tax_groups` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `tax_group_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `val_tax_groups` (`id`, `tax_group_name`) VALUES
(2, 'GST'),
(3, 'Chennai Tax');
```

`tax_mapping` is the table for mapping the `val_taxes` to `val_tax_groups`

```
CREATE TABLE `tax_mapping` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `valtaxgroups_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `valtaxes_id` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tax_mapping` (`id`, `valtaxgroups_id`, `valtaxes_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4);
```

Given all the tables and their descriptions, is the architecture correct? Or can we reduce it down to two tables without any duplications?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 entities (taxes and groups) joined as M:N. 3-table structure for to store this data is optimal in most cases. Additional recommendations:

1) declare id field in val_taxes and val_tax_groups as a primary key and alter their datatype to INT or BIGINT;

2) remove id field from tax_mapping table structure;

3) alter valtaxgroups_id and valtaxes_id datatype to INT or BIGINT;

4) define (valtaxgroups_id,valtaxes_id) field combination as primary key;

5) create foreign key references from valtaxgroups_id to val_tax_groups.id and from valtaxes_id to val_taxes.id.

– [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)